# prove/disprove Big-Oh

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I have the following function f(n), and I want to prove/disprove that it is O(n$^2$):

\begin{cases}
    4[sum(n/2,n)],& \text{if n is even } \\
    2n-1+sum(n-3,n),              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
(it should be 2 n-1, so a space between 2 and n)

where sum( j,k ) is a ‘partial arithmetic sum’ of the integers from j up to k, that is

\begin{cases}
    0& \text{if j>k } \\
    j + (j+1) + (j+2) + ... + k,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

e.g. sum(3,4) = 3 + 4 = 7, etc.
Note that sum(j,k) = sum(1,k) – sum(1,j-1)

How do I prove or disprove that this is O(n$^2$)?

Comment: Hint: there is an explicit formula for $sum(1,k)$, do you know it?
Google "arithmetic sum"

Comment: Is your sum(1,k) simply sum for $k$ first members of arithmetic progression?

Comment: @jjagmath I know that, I don't know how to prove/disprove O(n2) for this, im confused...

Comment: @zkutch Yes exactly.

Comment: Wrote hint - does it help?

Comment: I think I get it, so does it mean that it isO(n$^2$), or am i still wrong :/

Comment: Added more explanations to answer, including definition.

Comment: Please put ***all*** math inside math mode. Using math mode for just the subscript 2 in $O(n^2)$ looks awful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:$$1+2+3+\cdots +n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\leqslant n^2$$
As we know for non negative case $O(g)=\left\lbrace f: \exists C_f>0, \ \exists N,\ n>N,  f(n) \leqslant C_f g(n)\right\rbrace$.

So we can use $N=1$ and $C=1$ and find, that
$$1+2+3+\cdots +n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k \in O(n^2)$$

Comment: thank you, i get it now :D