# proving big-Oh for a function

Tags: asymptotics

I have the following function, and I want to prove/disprove that it is $\Omega$(n$^2$):

\begin{cases}
    4[sum(n/2,n)],& \text{if n is even } \\
    2n-1+sum(n-3,n),              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
(it should be 2 n-1, so a space between 2 and n)

where sum( j,k ) is a ‘partial arithmetic sum’ of the integers from j up to k, that is

\begin{cases}
    0& \text{if j>k } \\
    j + (j+1) + (j+2) + ... + k,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

e.g. sum(3,4) = 3 + 4 = 7, etc.
Note that sum(j,k) = sum(1,k) – sum(1,j-1)

I tried to solve it, however have not come across one before where it has conditions...

Comment: It's same? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3800737/prove-disprove-big-oh/3800773#3800773

Comment: I'm still confused...

Comment: Then ask more precisely - what you want to know?

Comment: Im confused as to how you got the first equation

Comment: It is simply sum of $n$ first members of arithmetic progression https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression

Comment: but what about the rest of the function, there are other parts too, wouldnt these parts effect the big O?¿

Comment: Write as answer. Look and ask, please, if you have something else unclear.

Comment: Okay I get it for big-Oh, but for big-Omega, would it not be Ω(^2)?

Comment: $\Omega$ added to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first line you had answer from estimating sum of $n$ first members of arithmetic progression.

Second line is $2n-1$ plus member, which we already estimate. But $2n-1 \leqslant n^2$, so this member is also $O(n^2)$. Now you can use property, that $O(n^2) + O(n^2) = O(n^2)$ and you are done.

Now about $\Omega(n^2)$: For first line i.e. where is sum of $n$ first natural numbers we have $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\geqslant \frac{n^2}{2}$, so we have definition of $\Omega$ for $N=1,C=\frac{1}{2}$. But for second line, as we have there member $2n-1$, then it is impossible to estimate it from down with multiple of $n^2$. It is possible to speak about $\Omega(n)$, so summing, about $\Theta(n)$.